# How can I find the values in a table that occur more than once?

Tags: duplicates, field, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a table with some fields that have the same value in more than one record. I want to get these values that occur more than once.

So far I tried to use the following code to write the field values to the infolog. But this implementation writes all values, not just the ones that occur more than once:

```
while select myTable
{
    info(strFmt("%1" ,  myTable.getFieldValue("myFieldName") )) ;
}
```

How could I change this implementation to only get the values that occur more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand your question, but this may help you:

```
static void test(Args _args)
{
    InventTable inventTable;
    ;
    while select count(RecId) from inventTable 
        group by InventTable.ItemType
    {
        info(strFmt("%1 - %2" ,  inventTable.getFieldValue("ItemType"), inventTable.getFieldValue("RecId"))) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Maxim Lazarev,
your Job it's good, but with this way I stamp to video all field's values.

I wanto to stamp only values repeated.
For example if I only have two record with same value in CustAccount-field, I find this record and stamp just this value CustAccount.
I know is not well written my question. 

Thanks!

Comment: In my example, RecId field will store the number of concurrences, so you can add `if (inventTable.recId > 1)`, this way it will only show records with more than one repetition.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful!
Have a nice day!